# Wallet spam ads getting out of control

Tags: feature-request, spam

Over the past several weeks I have seen a large rise in the number of a certain type of spam questions.  They are mainly advertising some kind of customer support for digital wallet services.  Here is a screen capture from one such recent spam (I just hopped over here after flagging it as spam):

[image]

I was wondering if it might make sense for SO to improve its filters, to not allow submitting such a question in the first place.  By the way, these spam ads also tend to have a UTF-8 red phone icon in their title.

Comment: flag spam as spam, don't vote to close it.

Comment: @RobertLongson `voting to close as spam` ... I didn't vote to close, I voted it as spam.

Comment: "*By the way, these spam ads also tend to have a UTF-8 red phone icon in their title.*" not the most recent ones.

Comment: I just flagged two with same telephone number.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar [there quite a few from today alone](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/posts). The most aggressive ones share a phone number.

Comment: Has anyone called the number?

Comment: Can you modify that screenshot, removing the specific part? At least the phone number that the spammer wants to promote.

Comment: @PeterMortensen what's the chance that a person visiting Meta and interested in a question about wallet spam be stupid enough to use the promoted service? :) It's not like the phone's even indexed anywhere as it is in the screenshot

Comment: @OlegValter Isn't saving one person from themselves already enough reason to warrant the edit? Chance should have nothing to do with that decision really.

Comment: @Gimby I was just pointing out how unlikely it is to be important :) If you want to edit to save this poor soul, then by all means (although one might say they need some to get their net access restricted as well as a precautionary measure)

Comment: @Scratte Part of the problem is that they are aggressively spamming new phone numbers, it's not like they have a single number. (Some of the effects are vaguely amusing, like when they spam the wrong number for a service, or connect the wrong title with the body of the spam.)