# What can be done to stop the support number spam campaign?

Tags: discussion, spam

In the past few hours, we've gotten several dozen spam posts advertising support phone numbers, typically for Coinbase and QuickBooks. Unlike most spam campaigns, this one (from my vantage point in the Charcoal room) seems to be picking up in speed rather than slowing down.

Is there a reason that Stack Exchange and SpamRam can't stop the barrage? Is there anything particular about this attack that makes it special or is this just a sign that our current tools are obsolete?

Comment: St.ack.Exchan,ge supp_ortLine ☎️SE $NOV$ mods@ban h e l p

Comment: The [Stack Exchange  ☎️ Support  ☎️  line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doEqUhFiQS4):tm: you mean?

Comment: It previously peaked around here: [Wallet spam ads getting out of control](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410498) then died down slowly over time. I'm not sure if it was due to extra effort from anybody here or not, though. The new campaign seems to have started more aggressive.

Comment: the drill is the same as with any spam flood: Report to Smoke detector, either in Charcoal HQ or in SOCVR.

Comment: This of course isn't an answer... I'm not exactly sure exactly _how_ they would stop it. That said, IMO our tools are doing a great job. Charcoal has detected them, and they've all been killed with . Plus, as @rene said, we already have tools for it (post in Charcoal HQ or SOCVR).

Comment: The solution is simple. Identify and isolate the spammers and then force them to play deadly versions of kids games for the pleasure of a super-rich elite.

Comment: Well, it's a constant arms race of spammers vs. The Good People™. Spammers are probing for the limits, and it looks like they've found a hole that lets them push through their spam until SE adjusts the settings. The part I cannot yet is what is the prize that they are trying to receive as the result of a successful penetration: it's clear that nobody is going to click on their links or dial their numbers, so it must be some secondary goal here, such as their links being indexed by search engines of the world from a site with high rep. I think SE's goal #1 needs to be destroying that prize.

Comment: Spamming is cheap and easy. Given the amount of spam you can push out, the effort that went into developing new techniques amortizes down to next to nothing. If you get so much as one moron per infested site, you probably profit..

Comment: Where those sample not detected? I mean, SE blocks a whole lot of those.

Comment: @Braiam Considering they were posted, no. Obligatory reminder that if SpamRam trips, the post cannot be _made_ in the first place, so them being posted and being here for us to be annoyed about is proof SpamRam isn't detecting it. (SmokeDetector doesn't really count in this context, because it's substantially more responsive through its use of user-generated regex. As far as I know, SpamRam takes a while to actually recognize posts that need to be blocked, and that assumes it isn't static in the first place.)

Comment: [A quick comment from the spam blocker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-eZeVwnVOo)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Is it essential to have the ☎️ in the title? Is it necessary for you too to annoy many people?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Another time, please don't do the spammer's job for them by including the *actual spam* in a meta post. We've removed the portion of the post titles which was the actual spam.

Comment: We already have automated systems in place for dealing with this spam, and... they're working. I personally worked, along with several other users, specifically on ensuring that this spam wave is being handled. We neither need to feature the spam on Meta, nor reveal our tricks to the spammer.

Comment: @Zoe when I said detected, I include every bot, system, etc. not just the ones that were blocked. My reference to "SE blocks a whole lot" is that I would've expected more in those 5 hours, so if those are the only ones found, then it's good.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how many spams got nuked vs the few that got through, but this would be interesting information for the spammers, too. I think I can stave off my curiosity in the name of the greater good.

Comment: @user4581301 We caught about 50 posts in this spam wave, going back about 24 hours. Not *entirely* sure how many did manage to get through despite our efforts, but I don't think there were any that escaped detection. If you do see one, please flag, of course.

Comment: By *We caught* do you mean mod and other concerned SO users tools or SO provided tools after posting? I'd expect SO's backend to gobble up countless attempts every second.

Comment: @user4581301 I mean the community-developed tools, which many of the moderators are closely involved with. There is a spam-blocking tool built into the site, called SpamRam, but as Zoe already mentioned, if SpamRam blocks it, it won't even get submitted, so we don't have statistics on those.

Comment: Groovy. I wasn't sure if SpamRam was corporate or community. The human-community won't have much trouble picking off anything that slipped through unless the tagging is particularly untraveled. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Whatever the site is currently doing, automated or otherwise, it's not nearly enough

Comment: Indeed, for reference we are now at about a rate of 50 such posts every 2 hours.

Comment: I reopened this because it's about a specific rather troublesome event, rather than spam in general, which each of the targets seem to be about (or they're just about the philosophy of spam in general, which is an odd dupe target for something like this).

Comment: I almost flagged this meta question as spam on reflex because of the title.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the spam is coming from an organized syndicate ring of Stack Overflowers who are trying to get easy flags and increase their flag count

Comment: @MFerguson That would be a lot of work for zero gain beyond, at best, a Deputy and Marshall flag (if they don't have them already). The people who would find the most use in that method would be people who auto flag, e.g. Charcoal members, which further defeats the point... and anyway most of those members already have the highest flag counts across the whole network... There has been a *lot* of spam lately from this recent thing, but still only a drop in the bucket compared to some of these users' helpful flag counts. I flagged maybe 20 spam posts yesterday, for ex. I have >15K helpful flags.

Comment: @MFerguson Also, I googled the phone number and a lot of forum sites are getting the same exact types of posts, so I don't think this is the case.

Comment: If title contains phone number and emoji..... auto ban user.

Comment: @epascarello: I fear that this would bump into a variation of the [Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)

Comment: I agree with @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't think "auto ban" is a good answer here. Imagine if I posted a poorly written question that looked like this: `Why doesn't the regex _____ match "555-123-9876 toll free MSFT support ☎️ ☎️"?!?!` it doesn't make sense to ban. Is it a bad title? Perhaps. Does "why does my regex not work" warrant a auto ban? Certainly not. It might even be decent question. Of course, in this example, I assume that the OP is asking about the regex, not trying to self-promote or spam.

Comment: @cocomac I have not see a title that detailed in ages.... lol "Why no work" seems to be a title most people use. lol

Comment: @epascarello I'm not saying it is a good title, I would personally probably downvote. _But_, I would also not say it warrants an insta-ban

Comment: @cocomac at best you could say it's a disallowed title, but these spammers have already demonstrated they're capable of abusing unicode. Even if we did somehow find the "ultimate regex" for detecting these titles, odds are they'll either find some other obscure and uncovered unicode character, or just... not include it in the title when they're blocked. The point being, I have to agree that title restrictions isn't really a viable strategy here. Whoever these spammers are, they're more sophisticated than your regular spammer, and I sadly have no doubt they'll get around it. They're already(1/2

Comment: periodically getting past SmokeDetector, and based on the volume, it seems they've found ways around the automatic IP-based ban systems. I'd love to see some functional and effective ways to block it, but a system block based on title regex isn't the solution for this particular wave. Unfortunately, because it's by far the easiest and fastest option to use

Comment: Honestly, I'm starting to think that simply blocking emoticons in the the title would more or less be enough right now. Emoticons have very minimal correct use on the site as it it, and they certainly don't belong in the title. That might block at least some of the crap we're getting. If the Emoticon is really important, it can be in the content of the post.

Comment: @Larnu Unfortunately, based on what we've seen, that would only stop some of it.  It doesn't all have emoji in it.

Comment: @RyanM, this is why I said some, not all.

Comment: Not sure I understand "we're getting a lot of them"... I have an extremely restrictive topic filter in place (`[java] or [xml] or [perl] or [xslt]`) and I'm seeing several per hour... which indicates to me that a lot are getting through.  I would think almost anything with a phone number in the title would qualify as SPAM, and using that as a criterion would cause very little collateral damage.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think the idea was that we have Smoke Detector to deal with this, so we don't have an issue simaler to [the blacklist of the word "problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115250/1081494). I could imagine a (valid) question with a title something like this: "Why doesn't my regex match the phone number 555-555-5555?" Would it be a good question? Maybe. Maybe not. But I forsee a repeat of the issue caused by banning the word "problem" if they banned phone numbers. Smoke Detector does a great job, anyways.

Comment: And they've started again here in April 2022. Whatever it was that used to work is now successfully being bypassed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And it's gaining momentum. While I have seen the odd spam now and then before, the current campaign is really taking on a new dimension at the moment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, there is more incoming spam. But glaring spam (support numbers…) typically gets deleted within 30 seconds, a few minutes _at the slowest_. So we’re doing pretty well at keeping it at bay. More subtle spam in answers can take longer, especially on smaller sites. But the obvious support numbers often get deleted within seconds of being posted

Comment: @cocomac I'm a very active user, I spend quite a few hours on SO every day. Normally I see spam maybe once or twice a month, at most. Now I see spam several times per hour. The last few days the problem has become several magnitudes worse. Sure they get removed quickly, but it's still a lot more work for the moderators that have to check the flagging (unless they've automated it?) and it's much more disruptive to regular readers flow. Right now I even saw three spams right next to each other, which I have never seen before. It's a menace.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - What gets me is the utter and complete pointlessness of it. "Oh, hey, look! A number where I can get Coinbase support! Yay!" said no one on Stack Overflow ever.